# ItemRenderer Vs ItemEditor

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

What is the Difference between ItemRenderer and ItemEditor?

And When ItemRenderer is initializing and loading?

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemRenderer is for configuring how something will *look* in a list control (i.e. a Picture + text might be a use case for an ItemRenderer). Thus "Render", how it will display (read-only).

ItemEditor is used when you want to override how the user might *change* the value in the list (assuming that you've set all the requisite editable properties on the controls in question to allow edits). A good example could be a date column. Perhaps you want a DataGrid to show a date as 12/28/2009 in the list, but when the user clicks on it, they get a DateChooser control to set a new date.