# Flex Column Color

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex-spark

I having a problem with contentColor / backgroundColor of a Spark DatagridColumn.

I have

```
<s:GridColumn> 
   <s:itemEditor >
   <fx:Component>
            --- < component like.. combobox>

        <fx:Component>           
   <s:itemEditor >
<s:GridColumn>
```

Well.. i tried to color that single column with a color (lets say "red"). I tried giving a className, setting up the background color, etc etc.

I noticed "conentColor" works but only when you click on the compoment to "edit" the cell, but i want to see the column's cells coloured even if im not editing them...

Any ideas??

Thanx so much!

Comment: Create a custom ItemRenderer too

Comment: Thanx! I added a itemRenderer Too, but it doesnt work to me. I want to see only the text, and when i click it, the itemEditor. But when im not editing, the styling is not being showed. Im using "defaulGridItemRenderer" with style, and with background color to try, and cant reach the result

Comment: `DefaultGridItemRenderer` is the renderer that is used by default. Assigning it explicitly won't change anything. You have to make your own ItemRenderer with custom background color.

Comment: Thanx a lot. Im learning some basics from flex, you helped so much!

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using an `ItemEditor`.

If you use an `ItemRenderer` as well you should be fine.

Check these out:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_3.html
- [ItemRenderer Vs ItemEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958745/itemrenderer-vs-itemeditor)